# Query not returning result when the program is executed from the compact disc

Tags: ms-access, vb6, ms-access-2003

I have build application in visual basic 6.0 and using access 2003 as database. My problem is that when I burn the application and the database in the c.d. and then run the application from the cd, the query return only one row. But when the application is run from the hard disk of the computer, it is working properly. Please help me, I am in a great trouble!!!

Comment: Are you referencing to the same db in both cases?

Comment: What's the simplest application you could write to replicate this issue?  Try that, it might make something obvious.  Also, if possible, post the query and VB6 query code here.

Comment: Side comments: "Run from CD" or a flash drive or a network drive requires special linking of the object code to work properly.  It won't impact the reported issue, but it will hammer the CD more than it needs to.  There is also the problem of components when deploying to CD, which should be done using reg-free COM.  Again, most likely not your problem.

Comment: @waqasahmed: Yes I am referencing to the same db named "test.mdb" in both cases.

Comment: @Scott: I tried all the possible things but it did not work. The query passed to the db is: "SELECT OrganizationName FROM OrganizationTable"

Comment: @Bob: The components are registered without any error from the cd and all the components works fine. But the problem is in the returning of the query passed by the application to the database.

Comment: One thing more to add in my problem: When the database is copied [from the cd] by the application to the windows directory[System32] or any other directory or drive, it does not work i.e. query return only one row. But when the database copied by the application is manually replaced by the same database i.e. [copy and paste the database in the same place], the query works fine, it return all the rows.

Comment: @Kushal - what OS are you using?  Is the file being blocked by Windows?  Right click on the non-working DB, go to properties, and see if there's an "unblock" button.

Comment: @Scott: I am using Windows 7, now it works fine in Windows 7 after I move the database from [System32] folder to the windows drive i.e. in my case C:\NCC\test.mdb. But now it is not working in Windows XP and Windows Vista. It is only returning one top row in Windows XP and Vista but working perfectly in Windows 7. No the DB is not locked, it is perfectly fine. I don't know what to do with this f***ing problem, giving me a lot of headache....

Comment: An MDB copied from a CD will end up read-only in the target file system.

Comment: @David: Thanks for the comment. How can we change the file from read only through the vb code?

Comment: My problem is solved... Thanks to all of the guys...

Comment: VB/VBA has GetAttr/SetAttr and statements which can be used to find out if a file is read-only and then to set it to read/write. The Access help outlines how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment given by Mr. David W Fenton is acceptable as an perfect answer for the question. Actually when the database is read only then it will not execute the query as we want to. So, always uncheck the read only mark. 
It will be better to copy the database from the cd to any drive of hard disk and then code the program to make the datbase normal (i.e. not read only). Then execute your query, it will return all the rows.